# Листание слайдера движением мыши

Tags: javascript

Возникла задача: листание меню движением мыши влево вправо. Само меню решено сделать слайдером (для облегчения работы). Но мышь. Не встречал ли кто готовых решений. Самому приходит в голову подсчитывать смещение влево вправо и, как достигнет определенного значения, вызывать событие смены слайда и сбрасывать счетчик

Answer (score 0):

Если вдруг кому будет интересно, решил так:

```
var mCounter = 0, mDirect = 'prev', mLast;
$('.block-menu').on('mousemove', function(e) {
    if(e.pageX > mLast) {
        if(mDirect == 'prev') {
            mDirect = 'next';
            mCounter = 0
        }
        ++mCounter
    }
    else if(e.pageX < mLast) {
        if(mDirect == 'next') {
            mDirect = 'prev';
            mCounter = 0
        }
        --mCounter
    }

    if (mCounter == 15) {
        owlMain.trigger('next.owl.carousel');
        mCounter = 0;
    }
    else if (mCounter == -15) {
        owlMain.trigger('prev.owl.carousel');
        mCounter = 0;
    }

    mLast = e.pageX
});
```